# www path to www2 redirect nginx

Tags: nginx

In my redirect rules I have a path that leads to a `www2` site.

Redirecting to other `www` type sites work fine so I'm wondering if there is something special I need to add here that I'm missing. Is there cache I need to clear to propogate these changes?

```
location / {
    #This one doesn't work?
    if ( $request_filename ~ /foo0 ) {
        rewrite ^ http://www2.example.com/foo0 permanent;
    }

    #Works fine
    if ( $request_filename ~ /foo1) {
        rewrite ^ http://sub1.example.com/? permanent;
    }

    #Works fine
    if ( $request_filename ~ /foo2 ) {
        rewrite ^ http://sub2.example.com/? permanent;
    }

    #All other requests good.
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
    }
}
```

Comment: [If is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace these if's with something like this

```
location ~ /foo0$ {
  return 301 http://www2.example.com/foo0;
}
location ~ /foo1$ {
  return 301 http://sub1.example.com;
}
location ~ /foo2$ {
  return 301 http://sub2.example.com;
}
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
}
```

Avoid [Taxing rewrites](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites) and [using if](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Using_If)

Comment: Thanks for the response Mohammad. I am having difficulty getting `try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;` to work. The `index.php` file actually bootstraps the application, so no matter what it has to run *after* a redirect. I suppose that's what makes this especially tricky.